# Exibir tabela excel no html

Tags: html, microsoft-excel, iframe

Olá pessoal estou tentando usar a tag iframe para por um visualizador de excel. Com pdf funciona, mas quando ponho um arquivo .xlsx ele faz o download do arqui ao ivés de vizualizar. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Geralmente os navegadores exibem arquivos PDF, mas Excel não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como.

XLSX é a extensão dos arquivos gerados pelo Microsoft Excel, um software proprietário não livre.
Diferente de extensões como PDF, JPEG, PNG, XML, MP3, MP4, etc, XLSX não é um padrão aberto, então não espere que seu navegador vá suportar esse formato no futuro.

O que você pode fazer é converter essas planilhas num formato como CSV, consumi-las e montar seu HTML com JavaScript.

Mas se você não têm experiencia com desenvolvimento, o que acredito que é o caso, é mais fácil utilizar o serviço de terceiros. O Google Docs por exemplo lhe permite importar as planilhas e então utilizar o próprio iframe que o Google provê a você.

Comment: E aqui está o link para fazer isso com o [Google Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en&visit_id=636865052766214133-2267974308&rd=3). :)

Comment: Para não ter o trabalho para consumi-las e criar uma table, só por um visualizador mesmo. Obgd pela resposta, ajudou bastante :D